# Choose Location of image.save in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, paint

so for my Pygame project where I have to make a Paint program, I want it so that the user can save the canvas to wherever they want on their Hard Drive.

I have it set up as:

```
cover = canvas.copy()

if saveRect.collidepoint(sp()):
    if mb[0] == 1:
        image.save(cover,"Untitled 1.png")
```

However, how do I make it so that the user can choose the exact location and file name in the Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [tkFileDialog of tkinter](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog).

Answer (score 0):

You can use tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename in python 3 like this:

```
win = tkinter.Tk()
win.withdraw()
name = asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[('Png files', '*.png'), ('Bmp files', '*.bmp')], defaultextension=('Png files', '*.png'))
win.destroy()
```